# How to login into Gamecenter without my password

Tags: games

How do I login to Gamecenter without my password

Answer (score 1):

Connor, you can't access Game Center without your iCloud password. Otherwise I could access your Game Center account without your permission using only your email address.

If you've forgotten your iCloud/Game Center password, as Tetsujin suspects you have, visit [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid) where you can reset it.